# Organize style of typography in project with styled-component

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, typography

I am have an app with React, TS and I want to use styled-components, but I am beginner in this library.

Would you help me to know about some good practices in configuring typography?
I mean enumeration of text types(h1-h6,body, text for buttons, text for something else) with defined font-sizing, font-weights and @media-queries.

Later I gonna implement these styles to ui components like buttons, inputs, etc.

Give me please some advices to organize typography with styled-components.